# Laravel fetch only pivot columns in many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, relational-database

I have a `User` model that relates to a `Section` model through a pivot model `UserTrainingSection`. I have a pivot table that stores the foreign keys for both tables called `section_user`.

I have 2 additional pivot table columns called `completed` and `completed_date`.

The problem I am having is that when I fetch my data it returns all the columns from the `User` model along with the additional pivot columns.

```
    class Section extends Model
    {
        public $table = "sections";

        public $fillable = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'parent',
            'position',
            'completion_percentage'
        ];

        public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'section_user')->using('App\Models\UserTrainingSection')->withPivot('completed', 'completed_date');
        }
    }
```

In my API service I fetch my data like this:

```
Section::with(['users' => function ($q) {
                $q->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id);
            }])->first();
```

How do I only return the pivot table columns and exclude the columns from the user table?

At the moment it returns something like this:

```
"sections": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Subsection 1 training",
                    "description": null,
                    "parent": 1,
                    "position": 2,
                    "completion_percentage": null,
                    "created_at": "2018-05-04 09:54:09",
                    "updated_at": "2018-05-11 09:14:59",
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Test",
                            "email": "test@test.com",
                            "created_at": "12-04-2018 14:51:42",
                            "updated_at": "2018-04-19 14:14:36",
                            "pivot": {
                                "section_id": 2,
                                "user_id": 1,
                                "completed": 1,
                                "completed_date": "31/05/2018",
                                "expires": "31/05/2019"
                            },
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

What I would like to return is something like this:

```
"sections": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Subsection 1 training",
                        "description": null,
                        "parent": 1,
                        "position": 2,
                        "completion_percentage": null,
                        "created_at": "2018-05-04 09:54:09",
                        "updated_at": "2018-05-11 09:14:59",
                        "users": [
                            {
                                "pivot": {
                                    "section_id": 2,
                                    "user_id": 1,
                                    "completed": 1,
                                    "completed_date": "31/05/2018",
                                    "expires": "31/05/2019"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

So I basically get rid of the user data I don't want and only return the pivot data.

Comment: It sound more like your db sould have three table. One for the user, one for the section and one for the training. No ? With three table `$user->trainings` will return what you want

Comment: I do have 3 tables, the `section_user` is the pivot table as it resolves the many to many relationship. The DB is not the problem, it's just how i filter out certain data from the relationship that i can't get my head around.

Comment: It's not what I want to said. Three table with an pivot table betweem user and training (and many another pivot between training and section if a training can have multiple section). You name your table `UserTrainingSection`  and this look like you have three different type of entites.

Comment: No, there are only 2 entities. `User` and `Section` - they are joined with a pivot table and model `UserTrainingSection`. Like I said, that's not the problem.

Comment: So what do you want to return ? The section with the complete date of ?

Comment: @DessaugesAntoine see my update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your expected output i guess you need data from junction model only, If that is the case i suggest you to define direct mapping of `Section` and `UserTrainingSection`

```
class Section extends Model
{

    public function training_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\UserTrainingSection', 'section_id');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'section_user')->using('App\Models\UserTrainingSection')->withPivot('completed', 'completed_date');
    }
}
```

In query you can simply do

```
Section::with('training_users')->first();
```

Comment: This is just what I wanted, Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

In your `with` statement you are fetching all `User` data by definition.
You can add a `select` statement to only get the results you want. You can add that either in the relationship in your model, or where you access the model in your API.

Example 1:

```
Section::with(['users' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('users.id', Auth::user()->id)->select('completed', 'completed_date');
}])->first();
```

Example 2:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'section_user')->using('App\Models\UserTrainingSection')->withPivot('completed', 'completed_date')->select('completed', 'completed_date');
    }
```

(Not tested)

[See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects)